# Display of another authentication enabled page content?

Tags: php, http

How to display content of other page which has authentication enabled?

Warning: file_get_contents(http://abc/report.cmd?report=123): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required in //html/tracker/index2.php on line 13

```
    $file_path = 'http://abc/report.cmd?report=123';
    $content=file_get_contents($file_path);
    echo $content;
```

Comment: [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) might do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the curl library to authenticate

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ; 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); 

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($curl);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Authenticate first.., then request the request the content.

Here's an example of authenticating against HTTP Basic auth w/ PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php